# Online C++ Grader Syntax Issue

Tags: c++, syntax, syntax-error

Im trying to use an online marker for a c++ programming site. The code runs fine on my computer. However, the site is repeatedly having a compilation error, spitting out these syntax errors:

/data/grader/2/81322/compile/source.cc: In function �int main()�:
/data/grader/2/81322/compile/source.cc:16: error: expected initializer before �:� token
/data/grader/2/81322/compile/source.cc:45: error: expected primary-expression at end of input
/data/grader/2/81322/compile/source.cc:45: error: expected �;� at end of input
/data/grader/2/81322/compile/source.cc:45: error: expected primary-expression at end of input
/data/grader/2/81322/compile/source.cc:45: error: expected �)� at end of input
/data/grader/2/81322/compile/source.cc:45: error: expected statement at end of input
/data/grader/2/81322/compile/source.cc:45: error: expected �}� at end of input
/data/grader/2/81322/compile/source.cc:45: error: expected �}� at end of input

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char vowels[] = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    string word;
    string newWord;
    getline(cin, word);
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)word.length(); i++) {
        bool vowel = false;
        char closest = 'z';
        int  close = 200;
        for (char &n : vowels) {
            if (n == word[i]) {
                vowel = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (abs(n-word[i]) < close) {
                closest = n;
                close = abs(n - word[i]);
            }
        }
        newWord += word[i];
        if (!vowel) {
            newWord += closest;
            if (word[i] == 'z') {
                newWord += 'z';
                break;
            }
            char next = word[i]+1;
            for (char n : vowels) {
                if (n == next) {
                    vowel = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            newWord += ((vowel) ? word[i] + 2:next);
        }
    }
    cout << newWord << endl;
    //system("pause");//remove
}
```

Being new to C++, I cant seem to make sense of this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've run into a similar problem before because the site's compiler was ridiculously out of date. If the site doesn't have a c++11 compiler, range-based for loops are probably syntax errors.